# Account_locked_balance import not found

Tags: nearprotocol

After updating near-bindgen and nearlib when trying to call one of our `viewMethods` through nearlib called `get_all_markets`

When calling the method I now get the following error:

> Querying call/flux-test39/get_all_markets failed: wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(LinkError("link error: Import not found, namespace: env, name: account_locked_balance")).
>   {
>   "error": "wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(LinkError(\"link error: Import not found, namespace: env, name: account_locked_balance\"))",
>   "logs": []
>   }

I see that account balance locks are exposed since the last commit, is there any documentation around this?

Comment: Seems like a bug. This is relatively new import, I can't see an implementation in the Runtime.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the PR (https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/pull/1714) that introduces `account_locked_balance` is not merged into `nearcore`. Sorry about this. Please use the previous version of `near-bindgen` for now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fix, sorry for that: https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/pull/1873

Comment: Still get the same error when using latest version of near-bindgen